# Docker container stops but won't return to shell

Tags: docker, alacritty

So I have my containers running with `docker-compose up --build`.
They were running fine. But when I stop them (with either `Ctrl-C` or `killall docker-compose`), my containers stops but the terminal won't go back to the normal prompt.

Tried to google but no luck. Any ideas?

(The blue line is after the first `Ctrl-C`. And the red errors happen if I tried to `Ctrl-C` again).

[SS of my Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q9Sa.png)
I'm on Docker version 20.10.12, My Terminal Emulator is alacritty, OS is 5.15.12-arch1-1 (my colleagues who are on MacOS and Windows don't have this problem).

Comment: May be specific to how you build the container. Some containers are more or less ignoring kill signals. Although in that case, docker(-compose) should force stop them at some point.

Comment: @TheFool: they are actually killed, my terminal just won't go back to the prompt.